# Android Alarm Clock will not ring when minimized

Tags: android, notifications, android-notifications, alarm, android-alarms

I recently started working on a pill reminder app as my school project so please keep in mind that I'm still in the learning process. I would like to make a repeating alarm that will ring when it's time for user to take the pill. I have managed to make an alarm that rings and shows notification but the problem is that it won't ring if I minimize or close the app. I have four classes currently: activity where you set the time 
, alarm receiver
,ringtone playing service
,activity with on and off button. The only time that alarm ring is when I leave app open and lock my phone or if I minimize and don't lock my phone.

I have tried to put this in activity where I set time:      alarm_manager.setInexactRepeating(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP,calendar.getTimeInMillis(),AlarmManager.INTERVAL_DAY, pending_intent);

And I have tried to put this in the pop-up window class:
    getWindow().addFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_KEEP_SCREEN_ON|
                WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_DISMISS_KEYGUARD|
                WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_SHOW_WHEN_LOCKED|
                WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_TURN_SCREEN_ON|
                WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_SHOW_WHEN_LOCKED);
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_activity_alarm_pop_up);
        this.context = this;
    final Intent my_intent = new Intent(this.context, AlarmReceiver.class);

I should mention that I have not figured out the notification problem yet. When alarm rings there is a notification in the pull down menu and when I click it, it sends me to alarm pop up activity where I have on and off button. Ideally I'd love to solve this that when alarm goes on it wakes up the screen with the on and off activity.

Any idea on how to solve my problem?

Comment: It seems you may want a started service to run in the background

Comment: Any suggestion on how I do that?